# How to create a graph with multiple series (1000) in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, r

I have an Excel worksheet with 1000 rows, each with 100 columns with numbers ordered from smallest to largest left to right (these are all dates, or years in which something has happened). I want to create an ordinal index for these dates, plotting each column by 1-100.

The following image shows an example of the graph I am interested. Here, I've only plotted 2 out of 1000 rows, but this is essentially what I'd like to do with the entire data set. [Example of scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qhdW.png)

Here is also a link to a screenshot of the Excel spreadsheet. So essentially, I am looking for a faster way to plot rows 1-1000 against row 1001.[Spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA2cg.png)

Is there any way to do this in Excel that is faster than creating 1000 series and selecting data 1000 times? Or is there another program to do this in? I feel like r would be useful but I haven't any experience at all in that program.

Comment: IMO, its worth rethinking what you're trying to accomplish by plotting 1000 series.  That's way more info than your eye will be able to discern.  So, are you trying to show things that could be better represented by distributions, central tendency, or some other summary measure?  For example, could a box/whiskers chart show what you need for your data?

Comment: I would prefer to display it in a different way, but right now I'm just working on recreating a model written by someone else, and want to see if I can get my graphs to look like theirs. Later when I modify it for my own purposes, I will try to display things differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a faster way. You can use a macro to create your plot programatically.

If you know VB, skip to step 3.

1. Open the Visual Basic window - either via Developer tab or Alt-F11.
2. In the top left corner there is a list of workbooks sheets and modules. Find the name of your workbook, right click on its name, and select "Insert > Module". In the file tree there should now be a folder called Modules, with an element called "Module1". Double click on it.
3. You are now in an Excel VB module. Add the following code:

   ```
   Sub chart()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
   ActiveChart.Legend.Delete
   i = 1
   numSeries = 1000
   Do While i < numSeries + 1
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$" & i & ":$CV$" & i
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Sheet1!$A$" & numSeries + 1 & ":$CV$" & numSeries + 1
     i = i + 1
   Loop
   End Sub
   ```
4. Run the code, either using the run button or menu in the Visual Basic window, or via the Developer tab in Excel.
5. You can see in the code the column names $A and $CV. Change these if the result doesn't match your data for some reason. the variable numSeries can be changed if you want a different number of rows later. This code assumes you have no header row, and that the X axis data is in the final row, which is an unusual way to store chart data, but matches your example.

Edit: 
X and Y switched:

```
Sub chart()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ActiveChart.Legend.Delete
i = 1
numSeries = 1000
Do While i < numSeries + 1
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Sheet1!$A$" & i & ":$CV$" & i
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$" & numSeries + 1 & ":$CV$" & numSeries + 1
  i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

and now attempting to get 1000 items under the 255 limit by having each series display 4 data sets:

```
Sub chart()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ActiveChart.Legend.Delete
i = 1
numSeries = 1000

s0 = "Sheet1!$A$" & numSeries + 1 & ":$CV$" & numSeries + 1


Do While i < (numSeries / 4 + 1)
  s1 = "=Sheet1!$A$" & i & ":$CV$" & i
  s2 = ", Sheet1!$A$" & i + numSeries / 4 & ":$CV$" & i + numSeries / 4
  s3 = ", Sheet1!$A$" & i + 2 * numSeries / 4 & ":$CV$" & i + 2 * numSeries / 4
  s4 = ", Sheet1!$A$" & i + 3 * numSeries / 4 & ":$CV$" & i + 3 * numSeries / 4


  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = s1 & s2 & s3 & s4
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=" & s0 & ", " & s0 & ", " & s0 & ", " & s0
  i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm actually interested in the final row (1-100) as the Y axis values. 

Excel also tells me there is a limit to 256 series - do you know of any workaround for that?

Comment: hopefully the third code block does what you need?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank  you. I haven't ever used VB so this is very helpful. The third code block, with the x and y values swapped again, works perfectly. This is for a model of surface feature visibility on a land form and the probability you might actually run in to what we are looking for. Thanks again!